# UISearchController showing fullscreen instead of a popup on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad, uisearchcontroller

I want to build a search control like the maps app; the search opens a result tableview (which works fine) on iPhone and should open a tableview in a popover on iPad. This used to be automatic in `UISearchDisplayController` but does not work anymore and it shows a fullscreen tableview on iPad.

```
self.resultsController = [[EFResultTableViewController alloc] init];
[self.resultsController.tableView setDelegate:(id<UITableViewDelegate>)self];

self.searchController =
    [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultsController];
[self.searchController setSearchResultsUpdater:(id<UISearchResultsUpdating>)self];

self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
[self.searchController.searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[self.searchController.searchBar setDelegate:(id<UISearchBarDelegate>)self];
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

`ResultTableViewController` is just a customised tableview. I do not want to write `IS_IPAD` conditional code. Is there anything I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe solution was pretty simple, you need to set the style on the controller, it shows a normal list on iPhone and popover on iPad automatically.

`[self.searchController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];`