# converting from UISearchDisplayController to UISearchController

Tags: ios8, uisearchcontroller

I have an app I am moving to ios8 and want to get ride of all the deprecated methods.

The app I have is an iPad app and I have a search bar in my navigation bar and the search result should appear in a popover under the search bar in the navigation item.

I have found the property that stops the search bar from hiding the navigation bar.

but I am still stuck.

Can anyone point me to a some sample code or describe the steps I need to take in order to achieve this.

Regards Christian

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not a step-by-step one, but question and answer might be helpful? [UISearchController showing fullscreen instead of a popup on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378846/uisearchcontroller-showing-fullscreen-instead-of-a-popup-on-ipad)

[self.searchController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];